# connecting multiple lines together in a text document and making them into a string to use

Tags: ruby

Trying to get a string of code to separate lines of text in a log based on the type of error they contain in the line (DEBUG, ERROR, INFO, FATAL, etc) and then separate them into different text documents. The problem is some error logs have more than one line to them without any clear delimiters between each error.

```
[07/07/14 00:05:32] <INFO >  701:                     - Warranty expires on 03/05/17
[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Recording dut_warranty_total as 1153
[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Requesting return count for CSXI4020108861
[07/07/14 00:05:33] <DEBUG>     :                     - Return information: {
  "count": 0,
  "week_ending": 0
}
[07/07/14 00:05:33] <INFO >  435:client_message       - Please scan or type the password for this unit:
```

As you can see the third "DEBUG" error has three consecutive lines after it containing various info, and I don't know how to wrap that into my code seen here:

```
log_file = File.open("07-07-14 to 07-13-14_debug.log")

File.readlines(log_file).each do |line|
  if line.include? "DEBUG" 
    puts line
    File.open("debug.txt", "a") do |out|
      out << line
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: How big will your files be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to remember when you should start printing out lines and when to stop, which is something one can implement with a boolean flag and some *if*-statements. But Ruby has this feature called a *flip-flop*, which is loved by some people and hated by others.

```
log_file = "07-07-14 to 07-13-14_debug.log"
File.open("debug.txt", "a") do |out|
  File.readlines(log_file).each do |line|
    if (line =~ /<DEBUG>/ .. line =~ /<(?!DEBUG).+>/) && line !~ /<(?!DEBUG).+>/
      puts line
      out << line
    end
  end
end
```

The range expression in the first part of the if condition starts false and becomes true whenever a line matching `/<DEBUG>/` is encountered. It becomes false again after a line matching `/<(?!DEBUG).+>/` is seen (which is the case for a line containing something like *<...>* where the *...* is not *DEBUG*. Then the process starts from the beginning. The second part of the if condition suppresses the output of the end line.

Depending on your exact scenario you may need to tweak and tighten the regular expressions.

Btw. i have rearranged your *File* statements. There's no need to open the output file every time you want to append a line to it.

Comment: "flip-flop" isn't a feature, it's an operator.

Comment: Just so I can better understand this for later, I'm curious as to what each special character in "/<(?!DEBUG).+>/)" stands for.

Comment: @user3850868 The "_(?!)_" is a [non capturing negative lookahead](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors). It matches an opening angle bracket that is _not immediately_ followed by _DEBUG_, followed by some other characters (_".+"_) and a closing angle bracket.

Answer (score 1):

About your code:

Don't do this:

```
File.readlines(log_file).each
```

You're asking Ruby to read the entire file into memory, split it into an array, then iterate the array. That is no faster than using `foreach`, whereas `foreach` is very scalable and won't fill all available memory if the input file is 50GB+ because it only reads a single line at a time.

About the problem - It's old-school. Here's how I'd go about it:

```
text = <<EOT
[07/07/14 00:05:32] <INFO >  701:                     - Warranty expires on 03/05/17
[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Recording dut_warranty_total as 1153
[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Requesting return count for CSXI4020108861
[07/07/14 00:05:33] <DEBUG>     :                     - Return information: {
  "count": 0,
  "week_ending": 0
}
[07/07/14 00:05:33] <INFO >  435:client_message       - Please scan or type the password for this unit: 
EOT

text.gsub(/\n/, '@@').gsub(/@@\[/, "\n[").gsub(/@@/, '').split("\n")
# => ["[07/07/14 00:05:32] <INFO >  701:                     - Warranty expires on 03/05/17",
#     "[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Recording dut_warranty_total as 1153",
#     "[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Requesting return count for CSXI4020108861",
#     "[07/07/14 00:05:33] <DEBUG>     :                     - Return information: {  \"count\": 0,  \"week_ending\": 0}",
#     "[07/07/14 00:05:33] <INFO >  435:client_message       - Please scan or type the password for this unit: "]
#     "07/07/14 00:05:33] <INFO >  435:client_message       - Please scan or type the password for this unit: @@"]
```

The trick is to replace the line-ends with a string that doesn't occur in the file normally. In this case I chose `"@@"`, which is often safe.

1. `gsub(/\n/, '@@')` replaces the existing line-ends with `@@`.
2. `gsub(/@@\[/, "\n[")` replaces all `@@[` with a new-line and `[` again, re-establishing the normal/desired lines.
3. `gsub(/@@/, '')` strips all remaining `@@`.
4. `split("\n")` breaks the text into an array of lines.

If the input file is small, you can use `group_by`:

```
lines = text.gsub(/\n/, '@@').gsub(/@@\[/, "\n[").gsub(/@@/, '').split("\n")
groups = lines.group_by{ |s| s[/\b(?:DEBUG|ERROR|INFO|FATAL)\b/] }
# => {"INFO"=>
#      ["[07/07/14 00:05:32] <INFO >  701:                     - Warranty expires on 03/05/17",
#       "[07/07/14 00:05:33] <INFO >  435:client_message       - Please scan or type the password for this unit: "],
#     "DEBUG"=>
#      ["[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Recording dut_warranty_total as 1153",
#       "[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Requesting return count for CSXI4020108861",
#       "[07/07/14 00:05:33] <DEBUG>     :                     - Return information: {  \"count\": 0,  \"week_ending\": 0}"]}
```

At this point, `groups` is a hash containing arrays of lines grouped together by their tag:

```
groups['INFO'] 
# => ["[07/07/14 00:05:32] <INFO >  701:                     - Warranty expires on 03/05/17",
#     "[07/07/14 00:05:33] <INFO >  435:client_message       - Please scan or type the password for this unit: "]

groups['DEBUG'] 
# => ["[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Recording dut_warranty_total as 1153",
#     "[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Requesting return count for CSXI4020108861",
#     "[07/07/14 00:05:33] <DEBUG>     :                     - Return information: {  \"count\": 0,  \"week_ending\": 0}"]
```

Now write the lines into a file:

```
File.write('INFO.txt', groups['INFO'].join("\n"))
```

or:

```
File.open('INFO.txt', 'w') { |fo| fo.puts groups['INFO'] }
```

with lines for each of the files you want to create.

Put all together, here's your code:

```
text = <<EOT
[07/07/14 00:05:32] <INFO >  701:                     - Warranty expires on 03/05/17
[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Recording dut_warranty_total as 1153
[07/07/14 00:05:32] <DEBUG>     :                     - Requesting return count for CSXI4020108861
[07/07/14 00:05:33] <DEBUG>     :                     - Return information: {
  "count": 0,
  "week_ending": 0
}
[07/07/14 00:05:33] <INFO >  435:client_message       - Please scan or type the password for this unit: 
EOT

lines = text.gsub(/\n/, '@@').gsub(/@@\[/, "\n[").gsub(/@@/, '').split("\n")
groups = lines.group_by{ |s| s[/\b(?:DEBUG|ERROR|INFO|FATAL)\b/] }
groups.keys.each do |group|
  File.write(group + '.txt', groups[group].join("\n"))
end
```

It's quite scalable on modern hardware and will be easy to maintain, simply by adding additional keys to the `group_by` regex.

Or, if the input file is big, you can use something like:

```
File.open('DEBUG.txt', 'w') do |debug|
  File.open('ERROR.txt', 'w') do |error|
    File.open('INFO.txt', 'w') do |info|
      File.open('FATAL.txt', 'w') do |fatal|
        lines.each do |l|
          fo = case l
          when /<DEBUG>/
            debug
          when /<ERROR>/
            error
          when /<INFO>/
            info
          when /<FATAL>/
            fatal
          else
            STDERR
          end
          fo.puts l
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is a bit more memory efficient than using `group_by` because it avoids creating the hash and new sub-arrays which have to be stored in memory.

There are tricks that can be played on Ruby's IO class by modifying the line-ending separator too. You'll have to do a bit of fix-up on the lines read, but it's minor:

```
File.open('DEBUG.txt', 'w') do |debug|
  File.open('ERROR.txt', 'w') do |error|
    File.open('INFO.txt', 'w') do |info|
      File.open('FATAL.txt', 'w') do |fatal|

        File.foreach("07-07-14 to 07-13-14_debug.log", "\n[") do |li|
          li = '[' + li[1..-2] if li[-1] = '['

          fo = case li
          when /<DEBUG>/
            debug
          when /<ERROR>/
            error
          when /<INFO>/
            info
          when /<FATAL>/
            fatal
          end

          fo.puts li.gsub(/\n/, '')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

That's untested, but it looks about right.

This sort of code is extremely scalable and fast. It's not as obvious what it's doing because `foreach` is doing the heavy-lifting as it reads the file looking for the line-separators.

Answer (score 0):

```
log_file = File.open("07-07-14 to 07-13-14_debug.log")

continued_error = false

File.readlines(log_file).each do |line|

 if continued_error
    puts line
    File.open("debug.txt", "a") do |out|
      out << line
    end
    continued_error = false if line.chomp.end_with?('}')
  else       
    if line.include? "DEBUG" 
      puts line
      File.open("debug.txt", "a") do |out|
        out << line
      end
      continued_error = true if line.chomp.end_with?('{')
    end
  end
end
```